# Calling method from server but it says its not valid

Tags: c#, php, service, methods

I have a service(C#) with this method:

```
<s:element name="ObterValoresDosTiposDeProdutoParaWebSite"><s:complexType><s:sequence><s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FK_TIPO_PRODUTO" type="s:int"/></s:sequence></s:complexType></s:element>
```

When I try to access it with PHP it returns me:

```
Function ("ObterValoresDosTiposDeProdutoParaWebSite") is not a valid method for this service
```

I'm 100% sure that the method is created on the service **TipoProdutoSO** and can access it via browser but my PHP insists on returning me this error message, here is my PHP:

```
$propriedades = new PropriedadesSoap();
        $propriedades->FK_TIPO_PRODUTO = $this->session->userdata('tipo_produto');

$material = new SoapClient(TipoProdutoSO, array("exceptions"=>1));
        $res = $material->ObterValoresDosTiposDeProdutoParaWebSite($propriedades);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected it was necessary to reboot IIS, we did that but got the same results, we had to reboot the windows...noob solution but it works.